# The mean and standard deviation of five observations are 9 and 0 respectively.Check body

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The mean and standard deviation of five observations are 9 and 0 respectively. If one of the observations is changed such that the mean of the new set of five observations becomes 10, what is their standard deviation?

Comment: I tried to solve it.I assumed that if the standard deviation is 0 and the mean 9 then the numbers must originally be 9,9,9,9,9 and the new numbers are supposed to be 9,9,9,9,14.There fore the mean is 10 and going by 9,9,9,9,14 the new s.d comes to be square rootof ((16+1+1+1+1)/5) ..so I am having my answer to be sqrt of 4 ..that is 2.Am i right?

Comment: Right idea, mistake in answer. Compute _**sample**_ standard deviation $S$ more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**

First, $n = 5, \bar X = 9$ and $S = 0$ imply that the five observations are $9, 9, 9, 9, 9.$

Second, if the new $\bar X = 10,$ then $n\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i = 50.$ So, what must the changed observation be? $\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i = 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + X_5 = 50.$ Solve for $X_5.$

Finally, find the standard deviation of $9,9,9,9,X_5.$